# MS Access: Trying to create an error if there is a duplicate record but code flags everything

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, debugging

I have a form that if a duplicate record is entered, the form creates an error message and prevents the record from being entered. However, my code is popping up the error message no matter what I'm putting in. My code is this...

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
    ' ToDo fix the labels in this function so they match the function name. Just cosmetic.
On Error GoTo Add_CmdSave_Click_Err

  On Error Resume Next
     
   ' ToDo fix the labels in this function so they match the function name. Just cosmetic.
On Error GoTo Add_CmdSave_Click_Err

  On Error Resume Next
     
    Me.cbCompletedTrainingID = Me.IntermediateID
    
    
    '
    Dim OKToSave As Boolean
    OKToSave = True

    If Not SomethingIn(Me.[fIntermediate FacultyID]) Then          ' Null
        Beep
        MsgBox "A faculty member is required", vbOKOnly, "Missing Information"
        OKToSave = False
    End If
    If Not SomethingIn(Me.[fIntermediate TrainingID]) Then
        Beep
        MsgBox "A training is required", vbOKOnly, "Missing Information"
        OKToSave = False
    Else
    
    Dim rs As Object

    Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
    rs.FindFirst "[IntermediateID] = " & Me.[fIntermediate FacultyID] And Me.[fIntermediate TrainingID]
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        Beep
        MsgBox "This person has already completed this training", vbOKOnly, "Duplicate Training Completion"
        OKToSave = False
    End If

       
    End If
    If OKToSave Then
        ' If we get this far, all data is valid and it's time to save
        Me.Dirty = False
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
        
       
    End If
      
Add_CmdSave_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Add_CmdSave_Click_Err:
    
    Resume Add_CmdSave_Click_Exit


End Sub
```

The issue, from my standpoint, lies in this part...

```
Dim rs As Object
    
        Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
        rs.FindFirst "[IntermediateID] = " & Me.[fIntermediate FacultyID] And Me.[fIntermediate TrainingID]
        If Not rs.EOF Then
            Beep
            MsgBox "This person has already completed this training", vbOKOnly, "Duplicate Training Completion"
            OKToSave = False
        End If
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271).

This line makes no sense as it is:

```vb
rs.FindFirst "[IntermediateID] = " & Me.[fIntermediate FacultyID] And Me.[fIntermediate TrainingID]
```

You probably want something like

```vb
S = "[IntermediateID] = " & Me.[fIntermediate FacultyID] & " And [TrainingID] = " & Me.[fIntermediate TrainingID]
Debug.Print S    ' Ctrl+G shows the output
rs.FindFirst S
```

Also, remove all these `On Error Resume Next` - this will happily ignore any errors, making debugging nearly impossible.

Also useful: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

And there is more: If [Recordset.FindFirst](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-findfirst-method-dao) doesn't find a match, it doesn't trigger `.EOF`. It sets the `.NoMatch` property.

```vb
rs.FindFirst S
If rs.NoMatch Then
    ' all is good, proceed to save
Else
    ' record exists
End If
```

Comment: so I tried this and it is still giving me the same problem

Comment: It works, except when there is a duplicate record, it doesn't throw up the error like intended. It just doesnt add the entry but without any indicator

Comment: Well, that depends on whether the old record can actually be found in `Me.Recordset.Clone`. The usual approach is to use e.g. `DLookup()` to check directly in the original table, not in the forms recordset. -- Or define a unique index on the two fields in the table, and then trap the error when the record cannot be saved because of the index. @JC3

Comment: I had tried the `DLookup()` but that wasn't working either and I was advised to try the `Recordset.Clone` approach.

Comment: Try the SQL from the answer as criteria. Otherwise I suggest to ask a new question with more details.

Comment: @andre is correct, the SQL in the FindFirst is incorrect in the the problem description. You wrote the SQL the way you you think if should work: it's not a Java logical expression , rather it's a SQL "WHERE" clause.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as intended:

```vb
Dim rs          As DAO.Recordset

Dim Criteria    As String
    
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

Criteria = "[IntermediateID] = " & Me![fIntermediate FacultyID].Value & " And [TrainingID] = " & Me![fIntermediate TrainingID].Value & ""

Debug.Print OKToSave, Criteria

rs.FindFirst Criteria
If Not rs.NoMatch Then
    Beep
    MsgBox "This person has already completed this training", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Duplicate Training Completion"
    OKToSave = False
End If
rs.Close

Debug.Print OKToSave
```

Comment: This works as well, except when there is a duplicate record, it doesn't throw up the error like intended. It just doesnt add the entry but without any indicator

Comment: So you are saying, it sets `OKToSave` to `False` but doesn't pop the message box? That I can't explain. Remove the error handling to debug.

Comment: Yeah, its stopping on the `If Not rs.NoMatch Then` but it skips the next 3 lines.

Comment: It makes no sense. Insert the lines with `Debug.Print` as shown, and tell us what is printed.